# How can I prevent Gitlab CI multiple yml includes from overriding a stage's jobs?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

In my Gitlab project, I'm including multiple .yml files. One of them is remote and the other is a template provided by Gitlab for Code Quality.

The .yml configuration is written like so:

```
include:
  - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml
  - remote: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkmarx-ltd/cx-flow/develop/templates/gitlab/v3/Checkmarx.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

Both of these templates are accessible. The first is located [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml), and the second Checkmarx one is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkmarx-ltd/cx-flow/develop/templates/gitlab/v3/Checkmarx.gitlab-ci.yml).

Both of these .yml configs define jobs that run in the `test` pipeline stage.

I'm having an issue where only the second include's jobs are running in the `test` stage, and the Gitlab Code Quality job is completely ignored. If I remove the external Checkmarx include, the Code Quality job runs just fine.

Normally I would just define separate stages, but since these .yml files do not belong to me, I cannot change the stage in which they run.

Is there a way to ensure the jobs all run in the `test` stage? If not, is there a way to override the stage a job from an external .yml runs in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, there seems to be some sort of rules conflict between the two templates, possibly due to the variables that the checkmarx template sets. Even though the CI Lint shows that all 4 jobs should run successfully, I can reproduce your issue with the above code.

Given that it's likely a rules issue, I overrode the rules for running the `code_quality` job and was able to get both running within the same pipeline:

```yaml
include:
  - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml
  - remote: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkmarx-ltd/cx-flow/develop/templates/gitlab/v3/Checkmarx.gitlab-ci.yml'

code_quality:
    rules:
        - when: on_success
```

You can lint the above changes to confirm they're successful (though GitLab will warn you that without any workflow:rules, you'll wind up with duplicate pipelines inside MRs, which is true).

You can also see the pipeline running with both jobs here though checkmarx fails because I don't have a subscription to test it with:

[image: Example Pipeline]

Comment: Great answer! I had actually done the same sort of solution, overriding code_quality to run on merge requests (I didn't know you could even override the behaviors in template jobs) - this ended up working. Now with your solution I'm wondering if there's any rhyme or reason, or if it's a bug on the Gitlab parsing end... Thank you!